# alertify.js - rails custom confirm dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, alertify

How can I customize my rails confirm dialog with alertify? I tried this code and regarding to the jquery_ujs it should work:

```
$.rails.confirm = function(msg){
  alertify.confirm(msg, function (e) {
    if (e) {
        return true;
    } else {
       return false;
    }
  });
};
```

example rails call:

```
<%= link_to system_communication_gallery_video_path(@gallery.id, video.id), method: :delete, remote: true, confirm: "Are you sure?" do %>
```

Comment: Are you getting a specific error? Can you share more code?

Comment: nope, I'm just getting nothing. The default browser specific dialog shows but not alertify. Calling alertify the manual way does work.

Comment: How are you calling $.rails.confirm?

Comment: Are you seeing any javascript errors in the console? It should work.

Comment: nope, no errors... that's strange

Comment: There's not enough information here to help you, unfortunately. What you've done looks right. It could be a load order thing.

Comment: when I check $.rails.confirm via firebug, it shows me my custom function. maybe I need to override another method?

Comment: ok... got it to work for 50% ;) Now alertify shows, but the cancel and ok buttons have no effect. The problem it wasn't working was some curious format issue within the code.

Comment: You'll probably want to check the alertify documentation for that stuff.

Comment: well... it's simple.... alertify doesn't support modal dialog. That's the reason it doesn't work. Just found it out.

Answer (score 2):

I am fiddling with this override as well and stumbled on this question.
This snippet does not work because the result of `alertify.confirm` does not get returned to `$.rails.confirm`.

**Update:**

After some searching I found a demo by [rors](http://rors.org/demos/custom-confirm-in-rails).

Important note: In your HTML you will have to have two data-attributes: `data-confirm` and `data-method`. Where data-method can be a RESTful method (GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE).

*Javascript:*

```
$.rails.allowAction = function(element){
    if( undefined === element.attr('data-confirm') ){
        return true;
    }

    $.rails.showConfirmDialog(element);
    return false;
};

$.rails.confirmed = function(element){
    element.removeAttr('data-confirm');
    element.trigger('click.rails');
};

$.rails.showConfirmDialog = function(element){
    var msg = element.data('confirm');
    alertify.confirm(msg, function(e){
        if(e){
            $.rails.confirmed(element);
        }
    })
};
```

*Haml:*

```
= link_to 'Link title', root_path, {data: {confirm: 'Are you sure you want to go home?', method: 'get'}}
```